# re-format timestamp to keep time and time zone

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

I want to create a table with date and timezone in different columns.
For example:

```
Date 20170311      Time 10:32:24+1300
```

[image: Example image]

The format has to be the same as above.

When I create the table Date was set as type date and time was type timestamp.

1. When I insert the date, I have to follow a certain format like 2017-03-11, how can I make it the same as the table shown.
2. When inserting the time and time zone, I have to insert the date alone with it, like '2017-03-22T10:37:50+1300' is there any way that I can reformat it?
3. After inserting with this format '2017-03-22T10:37:50+1300', the time and time zone changed in the table, how could I keep it the same as input?

```
CREATE TABLE example (id int, work_date date, sequence timestamp);

INSERT INTO example (id int, work_date date, sequence timestamp) VALUES (1, '2017-03-22', '2017-03-22T10:37:50+1300')
```

expected result:
1 20170322 10:37:50+1300

actual result:
1 2017-03-22 2017-03-21 21:37:50.000000+0000

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra has several data types related to date & time - `date`, `time`, and `timestamp`, and only the last one has the notion of the time zone.

The formatting of the timestamps is your responsibility - internally data is stored as long (8 bytes) [representing number of milliseconds since epoch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDataTypes.html#refDataTypes__timestamp), and then converted into textual representation by corresponding driver - in case of `cqlsh`, the formatting is controlled by [datetimeformat parameter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCqlshrc.html#cqlshCqlshrc__datetimeformate). Similarly, for `date` & `time` data types - they are kept as numbers inside database, not as strings.

If you're accessing the data from your own program, then you can format time as you want.